# Control how many post are displayed in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to control how many post are displayed for a custom post type in Wordpress, using only functions.php?
My query is not working for 'posts_per_page'.

```
    <?php
        $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;


            $query_args = array(
                'posts_per_page' => 8,
                'paged' => $paged
                                );
            $query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
            if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'workscat');
            $nameTerm = $terms[0]->name;
            $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'gallery-thumb');
            if(empty($thumbnail)){ $thumbnail = APP_URL . "images/works/no-image.jpg";}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pre_get_posts` action to do this in your `function.php` and below is the working code for it

```
<?php
function my_cptui_change_posts_per_page( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
       return;
    }

    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'posttype1' ) ) {
       $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 8 );
    }

    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'posttype2' ) ) {
       $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 12 );
    }
    //$query->is_category('mycategoryname')  remove this if you want for all taxonomy categories
    if ( $query->is_tax('mytaxonomyname') || $query->is_category('mycategoryname') ) {
        set_query_var('posts_per_page', 15);
    }

}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_cptui_change_posts_per_page' );
```

**Note : (If its not work please go to settings - permalinks and reset permalink)**

Tested and works well

Comment: It doesnt work well, it wors  perfectly well!!! Also a beautifull peace of code, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you’re working with Custom Post Types and your query is not returning anything, but you feel you did everything correct… go and reset the permalinks by visiting Settings >> Permalinks. Select **Default** press **Save Changes**, then switch it back to **Post Name** and press **Save Changes** again.

In addition, you can modify your main query and just have your archive template return the results, no need for new WP_Query object.

I would use the `pre_get_posts`  hook in your case and I would filter the main query. Add the following code to your functions.php

```
function set_posts_per_page_for_custom_cpt( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_post_type_archive( 'CustomPostType' ) ) 
    {
       $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '10' );
     }
   }
  add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'set_posts_per_page_for_custom_cpt' );
```

Place this code in your functions.php file.

Hope this helps

Comment: How could I use it for two diferent post types?

Comment: ex: posttype1=> 8posts, posttype2=> 12posts